# How to Disable Stack Trace Info in Go for any OS Executing the Binary

Tags: go, operating-system, backtrace

I am currently building a CLI using Go and am trying to disable any backtrace that is produced as a result of a panic. I believe my code has great error handling, but would now like to suppress any panic messages (fairly new to Go).

I currently put in the following in my main.go function (to purposely cause a panic):

```
var myarr [2]string
myarr[0] = "Foo"
myarr[1] = "Bar"
for i := range myarr {
    fmt.Println(myarr[i+1])
}
```

And I get this as a result:

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
Bar
panic: runtime error: index out of range [2] with length 2

main.main()
        {directory where main.go is located}/main.go:23 +0x207
```

How can I suppress this error such that anyone with the executable binary file will not be able to see this error?

I've tried utilizing the GOBACKTRACE environment variable when building my binary and setting its value to GOBACKTRACE=none, but this has no effect on other operating systems I've tested on.

Comment: Have you tried using `recover` in main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Burak mentioned you want to use the built-in Go function [recover](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#recover). There's a good Go blog post on all the subtleties of [panic and recovery](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover).

If you want to blanket cover your entire application stack, then simply register `recover` via a `defer` function at the `main` level:

```
func main() {

    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("unexpected problem encountered - aborting")
            // optionally log `r` to an exception log - so users may email to developer
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }()

    run(os.Args...)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/b8qYnlNZsr5

Comment: Considering most non-trivial go applications use goroutines in some way, this may not be much of a safeguard.

Comment: True - and OP would need to clarify - but most "frontend" `CLI`'s are single request/single goroutine in nature.

Comment: Also, not all panics are recoverable. See fatalpanic/fatalthrow in runtime/panic.go for details.

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried utilizing the GOBACKTRACE environment variable when building my binary and setting its value to GOBACKTRACE=none, but this has no effect on other operating systems I've tested on.

The environment variable is called [`GOTRACEBACK`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#hdr-Environment_Variables), not `GOBACKTRACE`.

Also, you can use [`debug.SetTraceback("none")`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/debug#SetTraceback) to achieve the same effect, although this can still be overridden via the `GOTRACEBACK` environment variable.

If you use the correct naming, it should work. If it does not work, congratulations: you found a bug in golang and you should likely report it.

As a side note, your program is panicking for a very good reason: you are trying to perform an out-of-bounds read on the array `myarr`; you will likely want to fix that so that the panic does not occur in the first place.